# Define an Extension Method for IEnumerable<T> which returns IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

How do I define an Extension Method for `IEnumerable<T>` which returns `IEnumerable<T>`?
The goal is to make the Extension Method available for all `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` can be an anonymous type.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The easiest way to write any iterator is with an iterator block, for example:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach(T value in data)
    {
        if(predicate(value)) yield return value;
    }
}
```

The key here is the "`yield return`", which turns the method into an iterator block, with the compiler generating an enumerator (`IEnumerator<T>`) that does the same. When called, generic type inference handles the `T` automatically, so you just need:

```
int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5};
var odd = data.Where(i=>i%2 != 0);
```

The above can be used with anonymous types just fine.

You can, of coure, specify the `T` if you want (as long as it isn't anonymous):

```
var odd = data.Where<int>(i=>i%2 != 0);
```

Re `IEnumerable` (non-generic), well, the simplest approach is for the caller to use `.Cast<T>(...)` or `.OfType<T>(...)` to get an `IEnumerable<T>` first. You can pass in `this IEnumerable` in the above, but the caller will have to specify `T` themselves, rather than having the compiler infer it. You can't use this with `T` being an anonymous type, so the moral here is: don't use the non-generic form of `IEnumerable` with anonymous types.

There are some slightly more complex scenarios where the method signature is such that the compiler can't identify the `T` (and of course you can't specify it for anonymous types). In those cases, it is usually possible to re-factor into a different signature that the compiler *can* use with inference (perhaps via a pass-thru method), but you'd need to post actual code to provide an answer here.

---

(updated)

Following discussion, here's a way to leverage `Cast<T>` with anonymous types. The key is to provide an argument that can be used for the type inference (even if the argument is never used). For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable data = new[] { new { Foo = "abc" }, new { Foo = "def" }, new { Foo = "ghi" } };
    var typed = data.Cast(() => new { Foo = "never used" });
    foreach (var item in typed)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Foo);
    }
}

// note that the template is not used, and we never need to pass one in...
public static IEnumerable<T> Cast<T>(this IEnumerable source, Func<T> template)
{
    return Enumerable.Cast<T>(source);
}
```

Comment: It's used, and provided, but not explicitly, rather it's being inferred... Without the C# compiler being "so smart" we'd be forced to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ExtentionTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            List<int> BigList = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15};
            IEnumerable<int> Smalllist = BigList.MyMethod();
            foreach (int v in Smalllist) {
                Console.WriteLine(v);
            }
        }

    }

    static class EnumExtentions {
        public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Container) {
            int Count = 1;
            foreach (T Element in Container) {
                if ((Count++ % 2) == 0)
                    yield return Element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a buffered iterator; it would generally be preferable to use an iterator block instead - i.e. drop the `List<T>`, and just "yield return Element" instead of Add.

Comment: (for context, the original version had a List<T> with .Add, finishing in return; I prefer the updated version ;-p)