# VS2015 LINQ in debugger watch window

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, watch-window

According to my source [Debugging lamba expression with VS2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx), LINQ should work in the debugger's watch window. However, I still receive the following error:

> error CS1061: 'IEnumerable<MyClass>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<MyClass>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Do I have to turn some option on? How to enable LINQ in the watch window? `System.Linq` is included via using in the file I'm currently debugging.

Comment: Does it work when you run the code in runtime?

Comment: What do you mean by "in runtime"?

Comment: i was wandering if you were missing a `using` but it seems not... And i also just noticed that you are trying vs 2015.

Comment: When the error occurs you should be able to hover over Linq variable to find out current value(s).  The error indicates the Linq variable is not a List<> object.  A Where will only work when the variable is a list that can be enumerated.  If the object is a class, then you must make the class IEnumerable or add a list object to the class that can be enumerated.

Comment: @jdweng: The object is of type `List<T>` and implements `IEnumerable<MyClass>`.

Comment: See following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277150/define-an-extension-method-for-ienumerablet-which-returns-ienumerablet

Comment: I don't think you're following my question. I do not want to write an extension method. I want to use *existing* LINQ extension methods in the Visual Studio debugger. `Where()` is defined for `IEnumerable<T>`, it should work.

Comment: You may need to make sure that you are using the new compiler

Comment: We're using Roslyn and new C# 6 features, so that cannot be the problem ... though I have to check, I think we're still on .NET 4.5.x, maybe an update to .NET 4.6.x solves the problem...I'll report back!

Comment: No, all settings are the same. I also created a sample solution where it works, there seems to be something specific about my current solution which prevents LINQ in the debugger's watch window...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the problem: Mono.Cecil-rewritten assemblies do not support extension method evaluation in the debugger (including LINQ extension methods) at the moment. I will extend this answer as soon as I have a workaround.

Here is the link to the Mono.Cecil GitHub issue: https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/issues/90

Comment: For anybody interested: the issue is fixed on cecil's master branch now.